# Easy way to make a Config file for Python?

Tags: python, config

How can I use a config file for a python program variables?

Following is a curl to send to telegram:

```py
#MSG _ Telegram if Firefox with Serpclix url&profile starts
def CurlKillFirefox():
    sleep(2)
    subprocess.call(['curl',
    '-X',
    'POST',
    '-d',
    'flow_x',
    (TGtoken,'KillFirefox_',Geraet)])
    #Time for Timestamps
    timenow = datetime.datetime.now()
    print("Curl KillFirefox", timenow)
    sleep(1)
    pass
```

Then I made a config file that I import:

```py
from configuration import config

TGtoken = str(config['TGtoken_URL'])
```

The config file:

```py
config = {
    "Geraet_Name": 'gary2acepc8gb',  # Name  to  ident  at  telegram
    "TGtoken_URL": 'https://api.telegram.org/bot525:AAGO_PGwc5Ivu0FRzA.....',  # Token url for telegram  complete  url
    "YellowBellXCoord": 355,  # YellowBellX Coords
    "YellowBellYCoord": 135,  # YellowBellY Coords
}
```

I need value as:

```
TGtoken = 'https://api.telegram.org/'
```

The URL needs the `''` to work.

How can I store these values inside config file?

I am getting errors like:

> syntax error or 'gary2acepc8gb' is  not definied

Answer (score 0):

In python you can use the `configparser` as described in the following documentation : https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

#### Example

Let us say you have a `config.ini` within the current folder :

```
# config.ini
[DEFAULT]
Geraet_Name = gary2acepc8gb
TGtoken_URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot525:AAGO_PGwc5Ivu0FRzA....."
YellowBellXCoord = 355
YellowBellYCoord = 135
```

You would use it in your case like this :

```py
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config.read('config.ini')

# Your code
TGtoken: str = config['DEFAULT']['TGtoken_URL']
```

Comment: sounds  nice  but got  error  , line 35, in <module>
    config = configparser.read('config.ini')
AttributeError: module 'configparser' has no attribute 'read', line 35, in <module>
    config = configparser.read('config.ini')
AttributeError: module 'configparser' has no attribute 'read'

Comment: @BillSian Yo, sorry I made a mistake! I corrected it above and I tested it, and it works !